# Running monit AND supervisord simulatenously. Any possible issues?

Tags: monitoring, monit, supervisord

Two aims:

1) Make sure background daemons such as webserver/rabbitmq are running all the time. If they crash they are automatically restarted etc. For this I am using monit with a config like:

```
set httpd port PORTNUM and
    use address localhost
    allow localhost

check process WEBSERVER with pidfile /var/run/WEBSERVER.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/WEBSERVER start"
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/WEBSERVER stop"
```

2) Run 'n' number of python processes simultaneously. For running these, supervisord is being used, with a config like:

```
[program:name]
command= somecommand
numprocs=3
process_name=%(process_num)s
```

Questions:
1. Could there be any issues with this approach? Or is it a bad idea in general ?
2. Is there a way to avoid this situation?

AFAIK supervisord needs everything to run in foreground and Monit cannot run multiple number of a script.

This will be 'dockerized' (In case that matters).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't foreseen any problem with this, even more if *supervisord* is managing another pool of tool than monit (a.k.a they don't overlap)

Monitoring *supervisord* with *Monit* could be a good idea to ensure its is always up.

As you state, monit is not able to handle several *same* process in a vanilla way.

Declaring several monit *service* and/or use of custom scripts are required.